# Best way to returns keys from object in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects like this:

```
var myArray = [{
    key: 2,
    value: 10,
},
{
    key: 5,
    value: 4,
},
{
    key: 3,
    value: 8,
},
{
    key: 12,
    value: 4,
}];
```

How is the most elegant way to convert this array in other just with the key numbers: `[2,5,3,12]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`array.map`**

```js
var myArray = [{
    key: 2,
    value: 10,
},
{
    key: 5,
    value: 4,
},
{
    key: 3,
    value: 8,
},
{
    key: 12,
    value: 4,
}];

console.log(myArray.map(a => a.key));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.map`:

```
const myKeys = myArray.map(i => i.key);
```